# 'HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN' alternative in POI 3.17

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using below code in POI 3.15 `'HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN'`

What is the alternative for this in POI 3.17

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using the `Enum` [BorderStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html#THIN). For example:

```
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Add Border");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Hope this can help you.
Thanks.

Comment: `style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);` give me what I needed. Thanks!